# Why does Installshield 2008 not roll back XML Changes?

Tags: xml, installshield

I am using Installshield 2008 Premier to edit some XML files which are already on the targetsystem. This process does work fine with the "XML file changes" function.

My problem is, that Installshield does not remove these changes on uninstall. I have set the "Remove element on uninstall" checkbox within the added element but InstallShield seems to consequently ignore this.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear solvable. Basically, the xml changes made during the install dont appear to be "finalized" until the installation actually completes.
Because of this, the xml file appears to get left with the "readonly" and "hidden" attributes set.

In my experience with IS2009, I've had to write an installScript to manually handle the changes (and removal).

There is a quite a lot of people with this issue over on the IS community forums, but sadly no official answer or acknowledgement..

Comment: Well, maybe they will solve this problem in the next version ;) Until then it will stay a manual task.